# How to send Return/Enter character to the Console using WriteConsoleInput/WriteConsole

Tags: c++, c, winapi, console, console-application

I have the following piece of code. I want to send the command "uci" and then Return/Enter to the console. However, I got no success doing so. Please kindly advise. Thank you!

```
#include <conio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>

DWORD WINAPI test(LPVOID lp)
{
    system("edit");

    return 0;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    /*
    HANDLE hConIn = CreateFile("CONIN$", GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE,
        FILE_SHARE_READ, NULL, OPEN_EXISTING,
        FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, 0);
    HANDLE hConOut = CreateFile("CONOUT$", GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE,
        FILE_SHARE_READ, NULL, OPEN_EXISTING,
        FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, 0);
    */
    HANDLE hConIn = GetStdHandle(STD_INPUT_HANDLE);
    HANDLE hConOut = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
    DWORD dwTmp;
    INPUT_RECORD ir[4];

    CreateThread(NULL, 0, test,(LPDWORD)0, 0, &dwTmp);

    Sleep( 1000 );

    ir[0].EventType = KEY_EVENT;
    ir[0].Event.KeyEvent.bKeyDown = TRUE;
    ir[0].Event.KeyEvent.dwControlKeyState = 0;
    ir[0].Event.KeyEvent.uChar.UnicodeChar = 'u';
    ir[0].Event.KeyEvent.wRepeatCount = 1;
    ir[0].Event.KeyEvent.wVirtualKeyCode = 'U';
    ir[0].Event.KeyEvent.wVirtualScanCode = MapVirtualKey('U', MAPVK_VK_TO_VSC);

    ir[1].EventType = KEY_EVENT;
    ir[1].Event.KeyEvent.bKeyDown = TRUE;
    ir[1].Event.KeyEvent.dwControlKeyState = 0;
    ir[1].Event.KeyEvent.uChar.UnicodeChar = 'c';
    ir[1].Event.KeyEvent.wRepeatCount = 1;
    ir[1].Event.KeyEvent.wVirtualKeyCode = 'C';
    ir[1].Event.KeyEvent.wVirtualScanCode = MapVirtualKey('C', MAPVK_VK_TO_VSC);

    ir[2].EventType = KEY_EVENT;
    ir[2].Event.KeyEvent.bKeyDown = TRUE;
    ir[2].Event.KeyEvent.dwControlKeyState = 0;
    ir[2].Event.KeyEvent.uChar.UnicodeChar = 'i';
    ir[2].Event.KeyEvent.wRepeatCount = 1;
    ir[2].Event.KeyEvent.wVirtualKeyCode = 'I';
    ir[2].Event.KeyEvent.wVirtualScanCode = MapVirtualKey('I', MAPVK_VK_TO_VSC);

    ir[3].EventType = KEY_EVENT;
    ir[3].Event.KeyEvent.bKeyDown = TRUE;
    ir[3].Event.KeyEvent.dwControlKeyState = 0;
    ir[3].Event.KeyEvent.uChar.UnicodeChar = '\n';
    ir[3].Event.KeyEvent.wRepeatCount = 1;
    ir[3].Event.KeyEvent.wVirtualKeyCode = '\n';
    ir[3].Event.KeyEvent.wVirtualScanCode = MapVirtualKey('\n', MAPVK_VK_TO_VSC);

    dwTmp = 0;
    WriteConsoleInput(hConIn, ir, 4, &dwTmp);
    //FlushConsoleInputBuffer(hConIn);
    //WriteConsole(hConIn, "uci\n", 5, &dwTmp, NULL);
    //printf(" dwTmp = %d ", dwTmp);

    Sleep(1000);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`\n` is a reserved key code; use `VK_RETURN` instead.

From https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/inputdev/virtual-key-codes