# C Programatically send Enter to cmd.exe by PID

Tags: c, windows, command-line, command-line-interface

The goal is to programatically hit Enter to some cmd.exe (running in background, e.g. owned by SYSTEM user, started from a windows service) which would visually result in a new, empty promt line like "C:\dev\sendenter>".

All i found on the net concentrates on receiving the keys where you have the option to check if ascii code 10 or 13 was sent. But when sending those to a running cmd.exe, all that will happen is that you get a newline but no new command prompt. Even using VK_RETURN which should be an alias for Carriage Return and Line Feed does not end up in a new prompt.

I believe the problem could be that WM_KEYUP or such must follow the ASCII key 10 or 13 but i was not able to find out how to send this using below minimal example.

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>

//argument: int PID of process
//compile with gcc, no options

//first and only argument: int PID
int main(int argc, char** argv){
    DWORD pid = atoi(argv[1]);
    printf ("Argument PID: %d\n",pid);

    if (!FreeConsole())
    {
        printf("Could not FreeConsole\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    if (!AttachConsole(pid)){
        printf("Error: could not attach console to specified PID\n");
        exit(2);
    }

    char s[] = {VK_RETURN};
    HANDLE stdoutt = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
    unsigned long cChars;
    WriteConsole(stdoutt, s, lstrlen(s), &cChars, NULL);

    return 0;
    
}
```

Comment: Does `lstrlen()` require a NUL terminated string? In this case you need `char s[] = {VK_RETURN, '\0'};`

Comment: good point, i was not sure if the null terminator is added automatically when defining the char array but i tested it with char s[] = {VK_RETURN, '\0'}; and it dont make a difference unfortunately. The receiving commandline just draws a newline but does not end up with a fresh prompt

Comment: I think you can try with `WriteConsoleInput` [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5880173/453348) a sample

Comment: i did read the post but not try it, now i did but the result stays the same for me, not 100% sure if i did what you had in mind @tttony https://pastebin.com/LCTYGcH1 in the end i dont think it matters if i write to stdin or stdout as soon as i attached to the other console, at least this is what i seem to experience

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tested on VS 2013

```
int main(int argc, char** argv){
    DWORD pid = atoi(argv[1]);

    if (!FreeConsole())
    {
        printf("Could not FreeConsole\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    if (!AttachConsole(pid)){
        printf("Error: could not attach console to specified PID\n");
        exit(2);
    }

    HANDLE hConsole = GetStdHandle(STD_INPUT_HANDLE);
    INPUT_RECORD ir[2];
    DWORD dwTmp = 0;
    
    ir[0].EventType = KEY_EVENT;
    ir[0].Event.KeyEvent.bKeyDown = TRUE;
    ir[0].Event.KeyEvent.dwControlKeyState = 0;
    ir[0].Event.KeyEvent.uChar.UnicodeChar = '\r';
    ir[0].Event.KeyEvent.wRepeatCount = 1;
    ir[0].Event.KeyEvent.wVirtualKeyCode = VK_RETURN;
    ir[0].Event.KeyEvent.wVirtualScanCode = MapVirtualKey(VK_RETURN, MAPVK_VK_TO_VSC);
    
    ir[1].EventType = KEY_EVENT;
    ir[1].Event.KeyEvent.bKeyDown = FALSE;
    ir[1].Event.KeyEvent.dwControlKeyState = 0;
    ir[1].Event.KeyEvent.uChar.UnicodeChar = '\r';
    ir[1].Event.KeyEvent.wRepeatCount = 1;
    ir[1].Event.KeyEvent.wVirtualKeyCode = VK_RETURN;
    ir[1].Event.KeyEvent.wVirtualScanCode = MapVirtualKey(VK_RETURN, MAPVK_VK_TO_VSC);
    
    WriteConsoleInput(hConsole, ir, 2, &dwTmp); // <-- 2 it's the number of inputs to send

    return 0;
}
```

I just tested with only `cmd.exe` opened and sending input to that process, at the beginning it only typed `?` in the console, that's because you have to send two inputs, the first with the `bKeyDown` to `TRUE` and later `FALSE` and `UnicodeChar` is setted to `\r` instead of `\n`

Also I had to set `wRepeatCount` to `1` because it was triggering asserts

Microsoft [says](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/key-event-record-str):

> wRepeatCount
>
> The repeat count, which indicates that a key is being held down. For
> example, when a key is held down, you might get five events with this
> member equal to 1, one event with this member equal to 5, or multiple
> events with this member greater than or equal to 1.

Remember that any `printf` will be sent to the attached console and can mess up the input